# Processing only the first occurrence of an element in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have an xml like

```
<A>
 <B>
    <C>90</C>
    <D>var 1</D>
 </B>
 <B>
    <C>90</C>
    <D>var 2</D>
 </B>
 <B>
    <C>90</C>
    <D>var 3</D>
 </B>
</A>
```

I need to show the value of element "C" only once (as the xml is being generated by third party and element "C" gets repeated in every node of B. Incorrect way , but I can do
nothing about it).

Now when I get value of C (using below) it gives me value as "909090" while I only need "90". How to go for it?? If somehow I can get list size and then divide the length 
of result string with the length the substring. But how to get list length.

```
<fo:table-row>
 <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block-container>
        <fo:block>C :: </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
 </fo:table-cell>
 <fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block-container>
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="A/B/C"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
 </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: Ah, you wish only the first "90" ... had a hard time trying to even figure out the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can always use `<xsl:apply-templates select="(A/B/C)[1]"/>` to process only the first `C` element.